# missing ios development signing identity for (null)

Tags: ios, xcode

when i try to generate ipa file, i am getting this error. Not able to solve.Please help me out to resolve this error:

[image]

i have own account , in my key chain access its shoeing like this :

[image]

i am not using new mac, i have already created ipa .Day before itself i have created. But today not able to do. i have .cer profile too.Its valid

Comment: Quit Xcode ->Restart your Mac and check once.

Comment: i did but still not working

Comment: Remove the account of user and then add it once time.

Comment: @user5513630 have u checked with this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/28924103/5362916

Comment: yes i removed and add again and i have my client provision profile and cer, and i need to create ipa file. So i use local signing assets to create ipa file

Comment: yes, but still that two error i mention in my image is not resolving

Comment: I’m having the same issue. I created many .ipa files but suddenly getting this error today.

Comment: have you resolve it?

Comment: NO :( I have tried many things like removing account from xcode, downloading provisioning profile again etc but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: This link may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services

Comment: i have added that new cer profile which is valid. But in my post i have mentioned the second image know. In that my client cer also says " This certificate has an invalid issuer". That not getting resolve. And also still getting that error like image 1

Comment: download this one and open https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 7 error: "Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821189/xcode-7-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's statement from Apple.

> Thanks for bringing this to the attention of the community and apologies for the issues you’ve been having. This issue stems from having a copy of the expired WWDR Intermediate certificate in both your System and Login keychains. To resolve the issue, you should first download and install the new WWDR intermediate certificate (by double-clicking on the file). Next, in the Keychain Access application, select the System keychain. Make sure to select “Show Expired Certificates” in the View menu and then delete the expired version of the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority Intermediate certificate (expired on February 14, 2016). Your certificates should now appear as valid in Keychain Access and be available to Xcode for submissions to the App Store.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/37208

1. Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer
   and double-click to install to **Keychain**.
2. Select **"View" -> "Show Expired Certificates"** in **Keychain** app.
3. Remove Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority certificates from "login" tab and "System" tab in Keychain app.

**Ensure the new downloaded cert is in both login and system** Default to only system tab will still give error.**

Comment: is it solved or still the issue is there? @MobileBloke

Comment: I think there is a general issue around codesigning- I actually logged an issue with Apple paid .  You need to make sure that the wwdr certificate permissions are set use system defaults as well . For some reason it doesn't always default to it !

Answer (score 3):

Open Keychain
Search for

> Apple world wide Developer relations certification authority

Delete this.

Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and add it to Keychain access > certificates

Worked for me.

Comment: But as i mention in my post i am getting my client cer is "This certificate has an invalid issuer".

Comment: I had exact same error and it has been resolved with the above mentioned trick.

Comment: you too have that cer is This certificate has an invalid issuer". Then ater you delete and add new `Apple world wide Developer relations certification authority` , You own cer is resolved??

Comment: Not just deleting it. Downloading the new one and adding it.

Comment: i delete that expire cer and download and add new, but still i mention in my second image . My client .cer is still " This crtificate has an invalid issure"

Comment: Delete the Apple’s certificate not yours.

Comment: i deleted apple certificate only dude. AND i download from your solution link and i added that. But still as i mention in my second image ( post ). My client certificate is still " This certificate has an invalid issure". so not able to generate ipa file stil same error getting

Answer (score 1):

If you still have this issue even after deleting and installing the new WWDRCA, make sure you deleted it as well in you system tab certificates

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this issue for a while so wanted to post what I found in case others run into a similar issue. I ran into the above issue after revoking my certificate while trying to export my build from a friend's machine. I found the best support by going step by step through this link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html

I would recommend following the steps in this link for anyone uploading a build to the Mac app store or exporting a Developer ID Signed Mac application.

There is a certificate called "Developer ID Certification Authority", this seems to be the one I was missing, and which caused the most trouble.

Another interesting thing to note is that the 10 digit letter/number ID for your Team/Distribution profile will be different than the ID for your developer profile. This should not throw you off, these two profiles work together.

Another good thing to know is that at the top of developer.apple.com there is a non-obvious drop down menu that lets you switch between iOS, tvOS, watchOS profiles and MacOS X profiles.
[image]

Another non-obvious UX issue when dealing with certificates is the system tab within Keychain Access. If you read that you should delete or change a property both within Login and within system, when they write system, they are referring to the system tab, which can be accessed within Key Chain access and can be seen at the bottom of this image:

[image]
This link is also helpful for certificate trouble shooting: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH5-SW11

But mainly just go through the steps in the first link given for exporting a Mac App with Developer ID Signing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the Apple Intermediate Certificate (Apple WWDR CA) is expired yesterday, 14 February 2016, on Saint Valentine. [https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/](http://Expiration%20Notice)

1- Update the system date to 13 February 2016. (IT’S WORKING FOR ME)

or

2- Open Keychain Access, and in the menu, click View -> Show Expired Certificates. Then, delete the expired Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority from both the login and System Keychains. Install the renewed certificate from Apple by downloading from https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and then opening it.

or

3- Follow the steps 1 and 2; only later change the system date to the current date.