# This certificate has an invalid issuer in ios keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate, app-distribution

Keychain show the certificate error > This certificate has an invalid issuer

See the screen shot.

[image]

RefLink>   [This certificate has an invalid issuer keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890084/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-keychain)

Also I have implemented the above url solution and ipa is created but at the time of uploading the build from Application Loader its show the error as per the screen shot.

Please help anyone.

[image]

Comment: This question is answered thousands times after Feb14 when apple's world wide certificate expired . Do you search even a single time before posting a question ?

Comment: Delete your old provisional profiles and install Apple world wide certificate . Download new provisional profile and clean build will work fine .

Comment: Just removed all the certificates and Reinstall and its shows  "This certificate has an invalid issuer " in key chain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading archive error: "Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397453/uploading-archive-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer
   and double-click to install to **Keychain**.
2. Select **"View" -> "Show Expired Certificates"** in **Keychain** app.
3. Remove Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority certificates from "login" tab and "System" tab in `Keychain` app.

**Ensure the new downloaded cert is in both login and system** Default to only system tab will still give error.**

4. Delete all your certificates and provisioning profile on developer portal.
5. Create certificate signing request from `keychain`.
6. Recreate all the certificate & provisioning profile using the CSR generated in step -5
7. Download and install those certificates created on step-6 and try.

Comment: OK I am trying again.

Comment: I have recreated the developer and distribution profile and its still show that error.

Comment: I have done all the things but still not resolved. I checked the Xcode preferences its show the ios Development and iosDistribution is revoked instead of valid. as per the image updated in the question. Can anyone confirm how this can resolved.

Comment: Finally done this question. I have missed the deleting of apple certificate from system. After removing that Invalid issuer is invalid keychain issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install new certificate from link below.

https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

This worked for me. I hope this will help you.

After this create and install new iOS Distribution and iOS Development Certificate.

Comment: I have downloaded this apple.cer and reinstall the iosDistribution and Development Certificate of app. But not resolved.

Comment: create new provisioning profile for app development,AdHoc and app distribution.And after that retry to upload or export your app.