# "This certificate has an invalid issuer" issue not resolved

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, certificate, ios-app-extension

In keychain my certificates is shown an invalid issuer. [image]

While I have correct "Apply world wide developer relations certificate authority" which will expire in 2023.

I have tried these links multiple time but no success

[This certificate has an invalid issuer : Keychain marks all certificates as "Invalid Issuer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402862/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-keychain-marks-all-certificates-as-inv)

Comment: has happened to me too, it is solved easily by entering new certificates apple as indicated above. but you have to control not to have them duplicated on system and login

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This certificate has an invalid issuer in ios keychain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505828/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-in-ios-keychain)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please check your solution on apple's forums [Uploading archive error](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/37208)

> Step 1 : Open Keychain Access in your mac.
>
> Step 2 : Go to View ->  show expired certificates.
>
> Step 3 : Select **Certificates** category. All certificate are there
>   which are expired or not.
>
> Step 4 :  Select **Login** and **System** tab, and Search **Apple Worldwide
>   Developer Relation Certificate Authority**  and delete it from
>   keychain.
>
> Step 5 : Now download the new certificate from : [AppleWWDRCA.cer](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer)
>
> Step 6 :  Go to download folder-> and double click on the certificate
>   to install it. Your certificate is successfully installed.

For more in detail you can also check below blog

[issue-this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-because-of-apple-worldwide-developer-relations-intermediate-certificate-expiration](http://ashishkakkad.com/2016/02/issue-this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-because-of-apple-worldwide-developer-relations-intermediate-certificate-expiration/)

Comment: Thank you.  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/37208 gets to that but in a very convoluted way.