# Cannot install Firebase using cocoapods. It says "Unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase, cocoapods

Any comments or suggestions? My pod file looks like this:

```
Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '8.0'

Uncomment this line if you're using Swift

use_frameworks!

target 'ScheduleBuilder' do

pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'

pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'

end
```

[image: The error I get when I try to install Firebase with cocoapods.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This certificate has an invalid issuer in ios keychain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505828/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-in-ios-keychain)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove and install curl again.

If you're using brew, then it's just:

brew uninstall curl
brew install curl
brew link curl --force

Or

Finally, You can solve it with this on Project Folder:

echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc